# Which standard errors?

Tags: multiple-regression, panel-data, standard-error, clustered-standard-errors, robust-standard-error

I'm working on a project with panel data and decided to use the fixed effect model, because the hausmann test p-value < 0,05.

No I wonder ho do I know, which standard errors should I use?
There are clustered by time, clustered by firm, clustered by both & robust standard errors and probably many more.

How do I know which one to use? Is there a test?

Probably the answer depends on some test, so here we go:

1. No normal distribution between the residuals of the model.
2. Data is heteroskedastic
3. VIF is okay
4. Autocorrelation between the residuals
5. Date is linear

I would love to get an answer, because this is eating up my time.

Comment: There is no simple answer/recipe. See for example [this article](https://economics.mit.edu/files/13927) discussing clustered standard error and fixed effects,

Comment: Danke dir @ArneJonasWarnke! :) Der Satz ist aus dem Paper: **This analysis
extends to the case where fixed effects are included in the regression at the level of a cluster, with the provision that if there is no heterogeneity in the treatment effects, one need not adjust standard errors for clustering once fixed effects are included.** 

Verstehe ich das richtig, dass wenn KEINE Heterogenität in den Behandlungseffekten vorliegt, man KEINE geclusterten standard errors benutzen muss, auch wenn mit fixed effects gearbeitet wird. 
Wie kann man auf Heterogenität in Behandlungseffekten testen?

Comment: Is there a way to test for heterogeneity is treatment effects?